# Visual Studio 2013 dark theme collapsed text color almost invisible

Tags: c#, configuration, visual-studio-2013

The Visual Studio 2013 dark theme collapsed text color is black (as shown at the figure below), because the background is almost pure black, The text becomes very hard to see.

I tried to change the collapsed text color at **Tools > Options > Environment > Fonts and colors > Collapsed text (Collapsed)**. I also have looked almost all others items and I was not able to find one that changes the collapsed text color.

Is that a bug? What is the correct item to change this color?

[image: Collapsed text is black]

EDIT:
I was using [edmuffin.MultiAdornment](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/03e958d5-66a5-4947-9d5e-334766cc5877?SRC=Home) extension. It overwrites the collapsed text color, that is why even after a restart the text color was not changing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I also faced the same issue and the trick is that you have to restart Visual Studio for the changes to be applied after you have made the necessary changes.(*No idea why or what is the exact reason for this but this has worked for me*)

Comment: After restart it is white, but I've changed it to red! Is that the correct item? I'm also using redmuffin.MultiAdornment extension, maybe it is conflicting or overwriting the comment color, but I still don't know which one is it.

Comment: @Pedro77:- I am not quite sure about redmuffin.MultiAdornment extension. But it could be bacuase of that. But I cannot be 100% sure for this. My issue got resolved when I restarted the VS.!

Comment: The item to change that is " Collapsed text (Collapsed) " ?

Comment: @Pedro77:- Yes that it the item!

Comment: Yes you are right. redmuffin.MultiAdornment extension was overwriting it. I have disabled it and now the collapsed text is red as it should be. And you are right about the need to restart.